# Testing Enyo Applications

Tags: karma-jasmine, enyo

I have an enyo kind like this:

```
enyo.kind({
    name:"branding", components: [
    {name: "appName", content:"Stars of the East", classes:"heading"},
    {content:AppConfig.tagline, classes:"subHeading"}]
});
```

I am trying to test this kind with the following jasmine `describe`.

```
describe("Test Branding Kind", function() {
    it("should see enyo component from jasmine", function() {
        var branding = enyo.kind({
            kind: "branding"
        });
        expect(branding.$.appName.getContent()).toBe("Stars of the East");
    })
});
```

I am getting an error. Can anyone guide me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually instantiate your kind to test it.  `enyo.kind()` only creates the template.  Try:

```
describe("Test Branding Kind", function() {
    it("should see enyo component from jasmine", function() {
        var localBranding = new branding();
        expect(localBranding.$.appName.getContent()).toBe("Stars of the East");
    })
});
```

You will also have to fix the problem that Art pointed out where you do not have the `components` block.

You will probably also need to actually render your components if they have UI elements you want to check.  You may want to change the localBranding line to:

```
var localBranding = new branding().renderInto(<some element on your page>);
```

Finally, we suggest that kind names should be uppercase to distinguish them from instance names.  `name: "branding"` would be `name: "Branding"` if you follow our advice.

Comment: By the time I have seen this, All your suggestions were incorporated. Am having following things to solve. Like how I can instantiate events, get the result from ajax proxy etc. Thanks, Accepting yours as correct.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your sub-components in a components array (you already have the closing bracket for the array in your code):

```
enyo.kind({
    name:"branding", components: [
    {name: "appName", content:"Stars of the East", classes:"heading"},
    {content:AppConfig.tagline, classes:"subHeading"}]
});
```